# Nuxt 500 require is not defined?

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

When starting a project on Node.js it gives an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eInxL.png)

node -v
v18.18.2

npm -v
9.8.1

package.json

````
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "nuxt": "^3.7.1",
    "vue": "^3.3.8",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/image": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.18.1",
    "nuxt-swiper": "^1.2.2",
    "ordered-uuid-v4": "^0.2.1",
    "swiper": "^11.0.4",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.6.5"
  }
}```
````

Comment: This isn't enough information to help you. It seems like you're trying to use common JS code inside of ES6 project. Are you using `require` anywhere?